# Search Service Application Log Viewer Page Search by URL, does it work?

Tags: search, logging

We have SharePoint Enterprise in our environment, on top of that we use the Search Server 2010 which works well except when I want to find a specific page in the Crawl Log.  If I want to see whether or not a page has been crawled I go to the Log Viewer page:

```
_admin/search/logviewer.aspx
```

When I try to look for a URL, even a Success one I can see on the page, I enter the complete URL in the URL or Host name Search By box and then press Search...and No Results.  I don't see any errors on the page or in the ULS log.  Has anyone had this page work?  I am not quite convinced that this has ever worked, although I am not sure why that would be when every other part of the SSA has worked; it would be very handy if it did.

While Alex's initial answer to this sort of resolved my problem with finding specific pages I can see that this issue still exists after SP1 is installed and I cannot get anything to return with the URL or Host name option enabled.

Does this feature work for anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be the normal (even though not optimal) behavior. You can search on web application level only. Searching for a single site, page or item will give you "0 results".

The only way I found to narrow the results is selecting a content source and apply additional filters like "Status" or "Start/End Time".

Comment: Sounds like what I have seen, although I hadn't tried the filters, will do so next time I need to do this.  Thanks!

Comment: I find myself needing this again and it STILL doesn't work after SP1.